# Dual WAN router configuration

Tags: networking, router, modem, wan

I have one ISP working (WAN1) at the moment on my Linksys LRT224 Dual WAN router.

I need to setup the second ISP in load balancing mode.  I did something so far (see image) but I am not sure if I am correct.

[image]

- DUAL WAN Router IP is 192.168.3.1 on my LAN (subnet 3 is used)
- WAN #1 is a optic fiber connection (I do not have acces to the modem, it isn't on my LAN, so its IP is 74.xxx.xxx.226).
- WAN #2 is a ADSL, that I have access to configure (disabled DHCP, and LAN IP is 192.168.2.1 where 2 is a subnet that I do not use, and 70.xxx.xxx.4 is a static IP provided by the ISP).

I have a few questions:

1. Do I need to put my ADSL modem on a different subnet?
2. Is the default gateway of my WAN2 the static IP for my ISP #2 ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the description or it is unclear. First, only one subnet should be used, or load balancing will not work. Second, the default gateway should either be dynamic on connection or is static  and given by the ISP (it is not your own static IP address).

Comment: The second subnet was suggested to me, but I didn't understand why...  makes sense to have it on the same subnet.   Default gateway is unknown to me.

Comment: Does the router demand that a default gateway be specified, or can it be left empty for automatic retrieval from the ISP?

Comment: My LRT224 offer these choices : Obtain IP automatically, Static IP, PPPoe, PPTP, L2TP and Transparent Bridge.

Comment: You may try to set the option of Obtain IP automatically. Only use Static IP with the address given to you if it doesn't work. Do not fill yourself the "Default gateway", as likely the router can get the two gateways automatically from the two ISPs.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to put my ADSL modem on a different subnet?

Only one subnet should be used, or load balancing will not work.
If one of the router's WAN interfaces is found on another network segment
than the computers on the local network, then no connection is possible.

> Is the default gateway of my WAN2 the static IP for my ISP #2 ?

No, the default gateway is whatever the ISP has defined on its network.
It is not your own IP address.
It is best to leave it unspecified, as in the normal flow of events
when the router connects the ISP will communicate the gateway to be used.

The gateway may change over time, so it is best to let the ISP specify it.
The ISP may also have several possible gateways and do its own load balancing.

Comment: Still need to test, but "Obtain IP automatically" did not work.

Comment: You could then get in touch with the Support of the ISP in question and ask for the right address.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to put ADSL modem into a bridge/bypass so that your WAN (static?) IP is assigned to your Linksys instead of the ADSL modem. This will disable DHCP & webGUI of ADSL modem so be sure to write down any unique settings as you'd have to factory reset it to reconfigure.

[Pg30 of your manual](https://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/MAN_LRT214-LRT224_8820-01696_RevC02_User_Guide.pdf) details how to setup the rest of the dual-WAN: Load balance or fail-over. You can also configure it to make certain connections use WAN 2 all the time if desired